# Deep count for object properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'd like to count the number of properties within an object.
I have found several solutions but none really counts the child\nested propertie.

For instance, I have the following JSON object.

```
{
        "id": "259a36d2-3852-425f-a70c-3f9477753210",
        "name": "foo",
        "type": "na",
        "text": "ABC.pdf",
        "left": 333,
        "top": 130,
        "w": 134,
        "h": 34,
        "customData": {
            "A": "fa6css4ec8-8ffb-55bca4dde06a",
            "name": "SDF.pdf",
            "IsExists": false,
            "PNumber": 1,
        }
    }
```

When trying the following I'm getting the result of 9, while I'm expecting 12 (which is the count of the entire properties).

```
JObject sourceJObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var res= sourceJObject.Count;
```

I'll be happy for assistant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JObject.Count` is [documented](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Count.htm) as returning the count of *child* tokens - not *all descendant* tokens. So while you may *want* 12, you shouldn't really *expect* 12.

If you want the count of all descendants, you can use `sourceJObject.Descendants().Count()`. However, that will give you 13 rather than 12, because `customData` itself is a token.

If you want "all descendant properties where the value isn't an object" you can use `OfType` and `Where`, as shown in the code below. You should probably think about what you want to do with arrays though...

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");

JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
var properties = jobject.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(prop => prop.Value is not JObject);

Console.WriteLine($"Count: {properties.Count()}");
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name} = {property.Value}");
}
```

Output:

```
Count: 12
id = 259a36d2-3852-425f-a70c-3f9477753210
name = foo
type = na
text = ABC.pdf
left = 333
top = 130
w = 134
h = 34
A = fa6css4ec8-8ffb-55bca4dde06a
name = SDF.pdf
IsExists = False
PNumber = 1
```

Comment: Great! what if I have a project with C# 8?
Looks like `prop.Value is not JObject` only supported in C# 9

Comment: @JumpIntoTheWater: Then you'd use `if (!(prop.Value is JObject))`

Comment: Or rather: `.Where(prop => !(prop.Value is JObject))` (I hadn't gone back to the code to see where the expression was used.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var obj=JObject.Parse(json);
    
    var count=0;
    CountProps(obj, ref count); // count=12

public void CountProps(JToken obj, ref int count)
{
    if (obj is JObject)
        foreach (var property in ((JObject)obj).Properties())
        {
            if (property.Value is JValue) count++;
            if (property.Value is JObject) CountProps(property.Value, ref count);
            if (property.Value is JArray) { count++; CountProps(property.Value, ref count); }
        }
    if (obj.GetType().Name == "JArray")
        foreach (var property in ((JArray)obj))
            if (property is JObject || property is JArray) CountProps(property, ref count);
}
```

Comment: What happens if  `property.Value.GetType().Name == JArray`?

Comment: @JumpIntoTheWater: Then we're getting into territory that you haven't described in your question.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using `obj.GetType().Name` to find out if the value of `obj` is a `JObject`. It's brittle in various ways - and it's what the `is` operator is for: `if (obj is JObject)`... except that doesn't require a typo-prone string literal, doesn't give false-positives on types in other namespaces, and handles subclasses. In general, comparing types by name like this is not a good idea.

Comment: @JumpIntoTheWater Thank you, I didn't know that you have arrays. I added arrays to my answer.